# waiting for https call to finish before doing for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, xmlhttprequest

So I'm trying to adapt some code. We were orginally just using a static json object in our javascript and now trying to pull it from our database to make it more dynamic for our users.

This is what we had

```
function sportToNid(sportparam){

    for (var i = 0, len = byu_teams.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(teams[i].name == sportparam){return teams[i].nid;}
    }
    return "all";

}
```

Teams is a static json object.

Now I thought i could just add a function that defines teams by an http request like this

```
function sportToNid(sportparam){
var teams = grabTeams();
    for (var i = 0, len = byu_teams.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(teams[i].name == sportparam){return teams[i].nid;}
    }
    return "all";

}
```

The grabTeams() would do a simple javascript http request which works but the for statement doesn't wait for it to return. How do I tell the for loop to wait for grabTeams() to get done before running through the rest of the cod using vanilla javascript.

Comment: If you are using jQuery and AJAX you can take a look at the async parameter, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JS promises, an example of an http request resolution can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises)